# Cast a swift dictionary ( [String:AnyObject] ) to a UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift, pointers, dictionary, casting

I have a swift dictionary, defined as [String:AnyObject] which I need to pass to the userdata parameter of addToolTipRect.

How can I perform this cast?

This does not work:

self.addToolTipRect( frame, owner: self, userData: UnsafeMutablePointer(thedata) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to cast the dictionary, just declare your dictionary as a variable with `var` then pass it as an inout argument using `&`:

```
var thedata:[String:AnyObject] = ...
self.addToolTipRect(frame, owner: self, userData: &thedata)
```